# Is it possible to use specific url address in return View for MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to add a specific link in Controller Method's return View ?

For example:

public ActionResult test()
{

return View("http://www.facebook.com")

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, if you want to return it as a plain string you could use a `ContentResult`:

```
public ActionResult test() {
    return Content("http://www.facebook.com");
}
```

or if you want to redirect to the given url use a `RedirectResult`:

```
public ActionResult test() {
    return Redirect("http://www.facebook.com");
}
```